# iOS - Some images not showing up in launch screen

Tags: ios, storyboard, image-manipulation, launch-screen

Hi we're having a really frustrating moment with the launch screens (note: NOT launch images).

The problem we're having is that some images appear on the launch screen whilst others do not.

The images are contained in a UIImageView and have some really simple contraints set up.

---

Here are some screenshots so you understand what we mean:

**First pic - A really simple avatar image (one color, RBG, Alpha channel) WORKS** [image: First pic - A really simple avatar image (one color, RBG, Alpha channel) WORKS]

**Second pic - A really simple logotype image (one OR multiple color, RBG, Alpha channel) DOES NOT WORK** [image: Second pic - A really simple logotype image (one OR multiple color, RBG, Alpha channel) DOES NOT WORK]

**Third pic - Interface builder look of the second picture. (What we want)** [image: Third pic - Interface builder of what we want]

---

Have anyone encountered the same behavior or am i missing something fundamental?

Another interesting thing is that it works as expected in the simulator but not on the actual device?!?

All derived data has been cleared and also the build folder multiple times.

Remember, this is NOT launch images, but rather the launch screen using storyboards.

Also, all assets are in the XCAssets folder.

Looking forward to some clarifications!

Alex

Comment: check device wise naming conventions for image

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Turns out that the physical device caches the images regardless if i removed the application or not. The only thing that actually worked was to 1. Remove the application and 2. Reboot the device. Only then the images would disappear. Don't know if this is a bug or not as of iOS 9.2

Comment: Has been an issue since iOS 9.0 and still and issue in iOS 9.3.1. Steps above resolved it for me.

Comment: I spent half day trying to figure out. Had to edit the image (just added one dot using pen tool in photoshop) and worked! Now changed some status bar settings and it disappeared again. Thanks for legendary solution. Saved my day :) Not sure if it would reappear at some on consumer's device :/

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to the alpha channel on the image. This is discussed on the dev forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19759

Answer (score 0):

keep image file in project navigator instead of XCAssets. That fixes my same issue.