# LaunchScreen not loading embedded image on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uiimage

I am working on a Xamarin.iOS app. We have an issue where our LaunchScreen sometimes do not load the image we are displaying in it. The bug is very transient and it only happens sometimes to certain users.

The thing is that when the image first is loaded on a device, it always shows up. On the other hand, if the image is not shown on a device, you can restart the app several times without it being loaded. Sometimes it helps to reboot the device. Sometimes an update/reinstall fixes it, sometimes it does not.

The image resource we are loading is not included as a On-Demand bundle resource, but is included in an Asset catalog.

I have been struggling with this bug for a while now. Sometimes I think I have fixed it, but then it suddenly shows up again.

I do see my launch screen being loaded, since the background color I have on it is displayed. It is only the image I am having the issue with.

I've seen this post, but it doesn't seem to be the same issue, as what I'm experiencing is in the production build from the app store. In debug builds, the splashscreen is loaded fine every time

[UIImageView missing images in Launch Screen on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579150/uiimageview-missing-images-in-launch-screen-on-device)

Anybody who can point into the direction I should look at? I can share some code for the xib launch screen or the asset catalog's json file if necessary.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200871/ios-some-images-not-showing-up-in-launch-screen maybe help.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. That might be what I am experiencing. However, what makes me think, that it's not just a caching issue, is that we are experiencing this on phones that has shown the splashscreen before. After an update - where we haven't done any changes to the launch screen, it disappears from some phones. Updating again usually solves the issue, but rebooting doesn't. Another thing, that makes me believe that we have a bug is that I think this is occurring often in our app, whereas I have never seen it happen in any other iOS app.